# Recieved event subtype is unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, event-handling, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am trying to detect if the back or forward slip button is pressed in control center, but when I run the following code, it crashes `if (receivedEvent.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack` saying `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170259890`. I'm not sure what is wrong and why it isn't working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNowPlayingItemChanged:) name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification object:self.player];
    [self.player beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
}

-(void)handleNowPlayingItemChanged :(UIEvent *)receivedEvent {
    NSLog(@"worked");
    if (receivedEvent.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack) {
        NSLog(@"next track");
    }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the complete error message. You left out the important parts.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you setup a handler for a notification using `NSNotificationCenter`, you have to be aware that the method you provide must be setup a specific way. From the docs for `addObserver:selector:name:`:

> Selector that specifies the message the receiver sends `notificationObserver` to notify it of the notification posting. The method specified by `notificationSelector` must have one and only one argument (an instance of `NSNotification`).

This means that your `handlePlayingItemChanged:` method must be:

```
- (void)handleNowPlayingItemChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"worked");

    MPMusicPlayerController *player = notification.object;
    // get the nowPlayingItem or any other property as needed
}
```

Comment: Changing it from `UIEvent` to `NSNotification` won't let me check the received event's subtype.

Comment: You can't. There is no event, just the notification. `UIEvent` is the wrong parameter type when setting up a selector for notification center.

Comment: All you know is that the item changed. The notification doesn't tell you how or in what direction. Determining that, if possible, is an entirely separate question from the one you asked here.

Comment: Again, this isn't an event. You are requesting to receive an `NSNotification`. That's not the same as a `UIEvent`.